# What is correct syntax for .htaccess 301 redirect of query based URL to new URL?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url

I wish to set up some 301 redirects to new URLs and I am trying to do this with the redirect facility in cPanel. For some reason the requests are not being processed correctly and I am guessing that this is because the old URLs are query based.

It looks like I will have to modify my *.htaccess* file manually and my question is: what is the correct syntax to use, based on the examples given below.

`http://www.mydomain.com/products.asp?category=42` needs redirecting to `http://www.mydomain.com/products/new-category`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cPanel will also not be able to determine whether you have other conflicting directives in your .htaccess file.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path part of the URL so you will need to use a `RewriteCond` directive with the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =category=42
RewriteRule ^products\.asp /products/new-category? [R=301,L]
```

The `=` at the start of the `RewriteCond` pattern essentially performs an exact (string) match (if that is required).

The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution removes the querystring from the request, otherwise it will be passed through unchanged.

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^category=5$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^products\.asp$ /products/new-category? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

Comment: I came across a useful tool (link below) which produces slightly different output, as in the comment above.

Both solution seem to work. Is first suggestion above the better option?

http://seo-website-designer.com/HtAccess-301-Redirect-Generator#heading-ToolResult

Comment: "Is first suggestion above the better option?" Yes. ;) To be honest there's not much in it, they both do the same thing. With mod_rewrite and particularly regex there can be several ways to achieve the same goal. However... `^category=5$` is a regex, as opposed to a simple string, as in my example. You don't appear to need a regex and are in fact doing an exact match so I would use the `=` (exact match) operator. `NC` (nocase) makes the comparison case-insensitive. Unless you specifically need this to be case-insensitive then don't use it. NE (noescape) is also unnecessary in this instance.